# How to Instantiate Enemy Prefabs Without Knowing the Name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

If I have many prefabs and I want to instantiate them all, how do I do it without having to rewrite the same code.

I think using a loop then calling Instantiate, but all prefabs are different name, so how can I put them in a list?

```
for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
   Instantiate(prefabName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a base class that all your `Enemies` inherit from.

```
public interface Enemy
{
}
```

Then make all your Enemy prefabs inherit from this.

```
public class Red_Enemy : MonoBehaviour, Enemy
{
}
```

Then in the class that spawns `Enemies` you can make an array.

```
public Enemy [] list;

foreach(Enemy e in list)
   Instantiate(e);
```

You can simply populate the `list` via the *Editor* by drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic name like `E1, E2, E3...` for enemies and keep enemy prefabs on a directory such as  **`Prefabs`> `Resources`> `PrefabName`**
and then you can use the loop as,

```
for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
   Instantiate(Resources.Load("E"+i), position, rotation); 
   // "E"+i for E1, E2 ...
```

Note:`Resources.Load()` looks for a path such as `Assets/Resources`